# Writing a C command prompt program with its own 'command line arguments'

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

Been stuck for hours at this. How do I read in command line arguments in my command prompt program and execute it using execv() system call? The following is the sample output where YWIMC is the prompt.

```
YWIMC > R /bin/ls
a.out ex2.c ...... //output from the “ls” command
YWIMC > R /bin/ls –l //same as executing “ls –l”
total 144
-rwx------ 1 sooyj compsc 8548 Aug 13 12:06 a.out
-rwx------ 1 sooyj compsc 6388 Aug 13 11:36 alarmClock
.................... //other files not shown
```

An R command has the syntax R command_path [arg1 to arg4] where they could be 0 to 4 arguments. E.g. R /bin/ls OR R /bin/ls -l

I'm supposed to use execv (I'm assuming its better for reading command line arguments since it uses a char array as its parameter and also cos my homework assignment requires me to) but I'm having trouble reading the arguments in.

How do I do this when there are any amount of arguments (0 to 4)?
While reading in arguments, how do I make the program recognise that that is the end of all the arguments I gave? (I had a problem where I would add an infinite number of arguments even though I set the max to 4.) The following was my existing code just that I have to change execl to execv

```
else    {
            result = fork();
            if(result != 0) {   //Parent Code
                childID = wait(&status);
            }
            else    {   //Child Code
                if(strcmp(filePath, "/bin/ls") == 0)    { //specific /bin/ls command
                    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
                }
                else    {   //run other programs
                    execl(filePath, NULL);
                }
                return 256;
            }
```

Comment: I don't get this -- are you supposed to write a tool named "R" that just executes it's first parameter with up to 4 arguments ... or are you supposed to implement a kind of "shell" knowing "R" as a command to do that? the latter would be a bit more work, forcing you to do some string processing (should quoting and escaping be supported?)

Comment: If it's the latter, maybe a [strtok-like function I wrote recently](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/string/string_strtok.c#L48) might help you, see [here for it's usage](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/doscrt0.c#L45)

Comment: it is sorta like the latter. writing a shell kind of program, reads in R and recognises that it's a "Request", reads the first parameter which is the file path, reads the next 4 arguments which could be none to 4. I have trouble doing a loop to read in the 0 to 4 arguments since I can't just take it off from the main method.

Comment: Yes, then your "main problem" is doing your own command-line parsing. At the most basic level, use `fgets()` and `strtok()` with a counter variable (see the respective man-pages). If you need to support quoting and escaping, see the function I linked above for a possible implementation of an extended `strqetok()` (called it like this for *quote and escape*). If you also want to support command-line editing, `fgets()` won't do any more, have a look at `libreadline` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of strings using `malloc`.   As you read in arguments, use `realloc` to increase the size of the array.  Then you can pass the resulting array to `execv`.

```
int arglen = 1;
char **args = malloc(arglen * sizeof(char *));
args[0] = strdup(/* program to run */);
while (/* more args to read */) {
    arglen++;
    args = realloc(args, arglen * sizeof(char *));
    args[arglen-1] = strdup(/* next arg */);
}
arglen++;
args = realloc(args, arglen * sizeof(char *));
args[arglen] = NULL;
...
execv(/* prog to call */, args);
```

Comment: i think my problem is more elementary than this. the idea i have in mind is to read file/filepath, take in all arguments, use execv(program,args). It's either impossible or i have a mental block but i can't seem to create a for loop to read in the arguments which could range from 0 to 4 arguments. i remember trying many things and while(scanf("%s", &args[i])) was one of them - i created an array args[5][20] before that.

Answer (score 0):

> the idea i have in mind is to read file/filepath, take in all
>   arguments, use execv(program,args).

You are on the right track. The exercise not only focuses on the use of `execv`, but subtly focuses on the command line argument indexes where you must pay attention to the fact that the **first argument given on the command line** has and **index of 1** (e.g. `argv[1]`), while the array needed to hold the arguments to pass to `execv` will begin at index `0`.

Handling the index offset isn't too difficult, you just have to pay attention to how you fill the array you will send to `execv`. **NOTE**: variable initialization is important. The `args` array you send to `execv` must have the final pointer be `NULL` to serve as a sentinel for `execv` to know where to stop processing arguments. One way to insure you provide a `NULL` pointer at the end of the array is to initialize **ALL** pointers to `NULL` to begin with:

```
char *args[5] = {NULL};
```

Then your only task is to insure you only fill the first 4 pointers in the array, leaving the last `NULL`. Also **note**, the first pointer in `args` must contain the **full-path** to the program you are executing. Your original example above showing `R ls` will not work unless you append the proper path to the beginning of `ls` (e.g. `/usr/bin/ls`). How you do that is up to you. With that a short example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *args[5] = {NULL};        /* all pointers initialized to NULL */
    int lim = argc < 5 ? argc : 5; /* limit the number of args to read */
    int nargs = lim - 1;           /* adjust the index to fill args    */
    int i;

    /* read the arguments from the command line */
    for (i = 1; i < lim; i++)
        args[i-1] = argv[i];

    /* output the arguments read */
    for (i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
        printf (" args[%d] = %s\n", i, args[i]);

    /* call execv (NOTE: you must provide a full-path
       to the program being executed, e.g. /usr/bin/ls) 
    */
    if (execv (args[0], args) == -1)
        fprintf (stderr, "error: execv failed - path correct?.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/execvargs execvargs.c
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/execvargs /usr/bin/ls
 args[0] = /usr/bin/ls
3darrayaddr.c                   getline_minimal.c             reallocptr.c
BoggleData.txt                  getline_rdfile.c              rec_char_in_str.c
<snip>

$ ./bin/execvargs /usr/bin/ls -l
 args[0] = /usr/bin/ls
 args[1] = -l
total 7528
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david     376 Sep 23  2014 3darrayaddr.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david     192 Jun 27 01:11 BoggleData.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    3565 Jun 26  2014 DoubleLinkedList-old.c
<snip>

$ ./bin/execvargs my dog has fleas and so does the cat
 args[0] = my
 args[1] = dog
 args[2] = has
 args[3] = fleas
error: execv failed - path correct?.
```

**Looking at execv a little closer**

If you would like to see how `execv` invokes the program you pass as `args[0]` you can create a small test script in your shell that will echo the arguments it recieves when invoked by `execv`. Something simple is fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0

for i in "$@"; do
    printf "  arg[%d] : %s\n" $cnt "$i"
    let cnt=cnt+1
done
```

Call it `test.sh` and make it executable. (e.g. `chmod 0755 test.sh`) Then provide `./test.sh` along with arguments of your choosing to your program:

```
$ ./bin/execvargs ./test.sh my dog has fleas
 args[0] = ./test.sh
 args[1] = my
 args[2] = dog
 args[3] = has
  arg[0] : my
  arg[1] : dog
  arg[2] : has
```

Comment: there is a problem here. i can't pick up command line arguments as you did from the main method. i'm using a command prompt to run another command prompt program which will pick up its own command line arguments. i don't just run the program with command line arguments then have the program(which is the command prompt) exit.

Comment: Hmm.. Now I'm confused. I thought you were going to call this program `R` and you were looking to have it pickup the second program to run and it's arguments. It's fixable, the only question is how much effort it will take. Let's start by understanding  what you mean by **i'm using a command prompt to run another command prompt program which will pick up its own command line arguments.** Are you saying you have something being invoked as `PROMPT_COMMAND` that is being executed as part of your prompt that is the issue?

Comment: Hold on, are you simply using `R` as the flag to tell *this* program to read the next path and arguments to pass to `execv` and that if `R` isn't specified, it should do nothing ?

Comment: there are other commands. i'm just having trouble reading in the arguments since it is not from the command line that everybody knows about which is from the main method.

Comment: So you need to see an example of reading arguments from a file. OK, will all the arguments be on the first line of the file, or one argument per line? If on the same line, what are they separated by? (space, tab, comma, semi-colon). I'll cook up an example, you let me know about the separator.

Comment: not from a file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534788/writing-an-interpreter-or-more-like-a-command-prompt-program I think this would give a better idea

Comment: See additional answer under [**Writing an interpreter or more like a command prompt program**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534788/writing-an-interpreter-or-more-like-a-command-prompt-program).

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the main problem is NOT the actual execution but the parsing of a command line in your own code. Therefore, I'm just giving the **most basic** solution here I can think of, heavily commented. It doesn't support *anything* like quoting, escaping, or editing of the command line by the user, but it should help understand the general concept -- try to use it as a starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PROMPT "YWIMC > "

/* read in a command */
static char **getCommand(void)
{
    /* static buffers, no need to allocate dynamically for a simple example */
    static char cmdline[1024]; /* command-line */
    static char *command[7];   /* parsed command */

    /* initialize empty command */
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    do
    {
        /* show prompt: */
        fputs(PROMPT, stdout);

        /* read commandline: */
        if (fgets(cmdline, 1024, stdin))
        {
            int i = 0;

            /* get first token (the command name) */
            if ((command[i++] = strtok(cmdline, " \r\n\t")))
            {
                /* get up to 5 additional tokens (the parameters) */
                while (i < 6 && (command[i++] = strtok(0, " \r\n\t")));
            }
        }
    } while (!(command[0])); /* until something was entered */

    return command;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* endless loop */
    while (1)
    {
        /* get next command */
        char **command = getCommand();

        /* and try to execute it */
        if (!strncmp(command[0], "Q", 1))
        {
            /* quit command */

            puts("k tnx bye.");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (!strncmp(command[0], "R", 1))
        {
            /* run command */

            /* check there was something to run given: */
            if (!command[1])
            {
                fputs("Command `R': Nothing to run.\n", stderr);
            }
            else
            {
                /* YOUR COMMAND EXECUTION GOES HERE */
                /* (try to create another "static" function for it) */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;

            /* some debugging on unrecognized commands */
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized command: `%s' (args: ",
                    command[i++]);

            while (command[i])
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "`%s' ", command[i++]);
            }
            fputs(")\n", stderr);
        }
    }
}
```

A key issue to understand is why `command` has 7 entries. The first one is reserved for your command. the last one should always be `NULL` (or `0`) so your code can detect the end of the arguments list. Leaves 5 usable parameters. If one of your command should run the first of it's parameters as an external command and allow 4 additional arguments, you need exactly those 5.