# Writing an interpreter or more like a command prompt program

Tags: c, command-prompt, execv

I'm supposed to write an interpreter program which is more like a command prompt. This is some background info:

```
General flow of basic interpreter
1. Prompt for user request.
2. Carry out the user request.
3. Unless user terminates the program, go to step 1.

Run a command. Format:
R command_path [arg1 to arg4]
//a single character ‘R’ which stands for 'Run', followed by the path of the command
//the user can supply up to 4 command line arguments
Behavior:
a. If command exist, run the command in a child process with the supplied
command line arguments
 Wait until the child process is done
b. Else print error message “XXXX not found”, where XXXX is the user
entered command
```

E.g.

```
YWIMC > R /bin/ls
a.out ex2.c ...... //output from the “ls” command
YWIMC > R /bin/ls –l //same as executing “ls –l”
total 144
-rwx------ 1 sooyj compsc 8548 Aug 13 12:06 a.out
-rwx------ 1 sooyj compsc 6388 Aug 13 11:36 alarmClock
.................... //other files not shown
```

the idea i have so far is, read in file path, read in arguments, use execv(filePath, args). however, i can't get the loop and the syntax right.

```
while(scanf("%s", args[i]) !=0)  { //read in arguments
     i++;
     }
execv(filePath,args);
```

this reads an infinite number of arguments. as i said i can't get the syntax right. processing strings in C is such a pain :(

Re-edited. This is my current code which is rather incomplete

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>      //For stat()
#include <sys/types.h>   
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>     //for fork(), wait()

int main()
{
    char request, filePath[100];
    int result, pathExist, childID, status;
    struct stat buf;

    //read user input
    printf("YWIMC > ");
    scanf("%c", &request);
    while (request != 'Q'){ //if 'Q' then just exit program
        // Handle 'R' request
        scanf("%s", &filePath); //Read the filePath/program name
        pathExist = stat(filePath, &buf);  
        if(pathExist  < 0)  {   
            printf("%s not found\n", filePath);
        }
        else    {
            result = fork();
            if(result != 0) {   //Parent Code
                childID = wait(&status);
            }
            else    {   //Child Code
                if(strcmp(filePath, "/bin/ls") == 0)    {
                    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL); //change to execv
                }                                 //with the use of a 2D
                                                  //string array
                else    {  //same for this
                    execl(filePath, NULL);
                }
                return 256;
            }
        }


        fflush(stdin);      //remove all left over inputs

        printf("YWIMC > ");
        scanf("%c", &request);
    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why not just perform `argc` iterations?

Comment: is argc a command line input? like.. if i have 3 arguments i have to enter in '3'. or does it sense automatically, i doubt so right?

Comment: Two general notes: One about C and security: **never ever** use `scanf("%s", ...)`, it's equivalent to [`gets(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) (see the section *BUGS* there). The other one about this site: I'd prefer to add to an original question (not deleting content that might invalidate already given answers) instead of posting an entirely new one. Well, I just left another answer over there.

Comment: Look inside the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) POSIX  [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) like `sash` or `bash`, or inside interpreters like [lua](http://lua.org/)

Comment: Alright felix understood! Thanks!

Comment: Another significant issue you face with `scanf` is leaving the trailing `\n'` in the input buffer. It will cause the next `scanf` to seem to be **skipped** (it really isn't skipped, it just takes the `'\n'` (char `0xa` or `10`) as your intended input and uses that). You asked about the `trimcrlf` function below that removes the trailing newline read by `fgets` or `getline`, you have the exact opposite problem with `scanf`. Instead of reading it, it leaves it in the buffer. You can control it. Look carefully at the man page and read about `'*'`, the *assignment-suppression character*.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is an error and does NOT do what you think it is doing. `fflush` flushes all characters from *output* buffers. You can do the same thing with `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`. Look at man *fflush*.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I think I finally understand what it is you want to do. To create your `YWIMC` interpreter environment and be able to handle both `command not found` and errors in the execution with the command passed to `execv` as well as returning to the `YWIMC` after a successful command, you have to `fork` the call to `execv` to a separate process to prevent `execv` from terminating the program.

Basically, you create the `YWIMC` shell with an outer `while` loop displaying the prompt and reading the command line (`cmdline`) on each iteration. Within the loop, the easiest way to separate the command line is with `strtok` or `strsep` (`strtok`) used below. You can make that process simple by calling `strtok` in a `for` loop:

```
    for (p = strtok (line, " \n"); 
            p && i < MAXA - 1;
            p = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
        cmdline[i++] = strdup (p);
```

**Note:** `strtok` modifies the original string, so you must make a copy of the string to be able to provide the `error` message containing the original command line.

If the users enters a request `R` as the first token and it has at least one additional argument, you `fork` the process. In the child (`pid == 0`) you pass the proper `/path/to/command` and arguments to `execv`. The easiest way to pass the proper command and arguments is to create a pointer `args` that points to the second element of `cmdline` (so that `R` is effectively discarded from the array passed to `execv`). You also need to provide a way for the child process to exit in the event a bad command is passed to `execv` (otherwise the user will wonder why they must enter `q` twice to exit after a bad command is passed.)

At that point, it is up to `execv` to execute the command, or fail with an error provided on failure. When the users enter `q` the shell will need to free all memory allocated by `strdup` and then exit.

Try the following and let me know if I finally understood what you were attempting to do. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* MAXC - maximum characters that can be entered by user at prompt
   MAXA - maximum arguments to read (R + path + 1 2 3 4 + NULL) */
#define MAXC 256
#define MAXA 7

void trimcrnl (char *s);

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXC] = {0};

    printf ("\n Entering 'YWIMC' environment\n"
            "   usage: R command_path [arg1 to arg4]\n"
            "          ('q' to quit).\n\n");

    while (printf ("YWIMC > ") &&
        fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) 
    {
        if (*line == 'q') break;
        if (*line != 'R') continue;

        trimcrnl (line);  /* strip newline from end of line */

        char *p = line;
        char *cmdline[MAXA] = {NULL};
        char **args = &cmdline[1];
        char *err = strdup (line);
        int i = 0, nargs = 0, status = 0;
        pid_t pid;

        /* parse line into separate tokens (arguments) */
        for (p = strtok (line, " \n"); 
                p && i < MAXA - 1;
                p = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
            cmdline[i++] = strdup (p);

        nargs = i;  /* save the number of arguments found */

        if (nargs < 2) continue;

#ifdef DEBUG
        /* output command line & arguments read */
        for (i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
            printf (" cmdline[%d] = %s\n", i, cmdline[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < nargs - 1; i++)
            printf (" args[%d] = %s\n", i, args[i]);
#endif
        if ((pid = fork ()) == -1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: fork failed returning -1.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
            /* call execv (NOTE: you must provide a full-path
               to the program being executed, e.g. /usr/bin/ls)
            */
            if (execv (args[0], args) == -1)
                fprintf (stderr, "error: '%s' not found.\n", err);
            _exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        waitpid (pid, &status, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

/* strip newline or carriage return from string 's' */
void trimcrnl (char *s)
{
    if (!s) return;

    size_t len = strlen (s);
    while (len > 0 && (s[len-1] == '\n' || s[len-1] == '\r'))
        s[--len] = 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/execvargs execvargs.c
```

or to compile with debug output enabled:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/execvargs execvargs.c -DDEBUG
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/execvargsfile

 Entering 'YWIMC' environment
   usage: R command_path [arg1 to arg4]
          ('q' to quit).

YWIMC > anything not starting with 'R'
YWIMC > R badpath badcommand
error: 'R badpath badcommand' not found.
YWIMC > R /bin/ls /home/david/cnf/LVM
Lvm.pdf
YWIMC > R /bin/ls -al /home/david/cnf/LVM
total 380
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david   4096 May 21 22:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 david david   4096 Aug 27 17:58 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david 380862 May 21 22:22 Lvm.pdf
YWIMC > q
```

Comment: I don't understand a few things. And I did my code from a different perspective, maybe you could take a look. I really like your answer though! I don't really know how the trimcnrl works (just probably syntax issue) and the for loop with the strtok (syntax too). Also it's probably cos I'm super confused when it comes to pointers in C. thank you so much for the help. i can't find help anywhere else including my school forum :(

Comment: The trimcrnl is nothing more than a "Trim Carriage Return/New Line" from the end of `line`. It is only needed so the error message doesn't print followed by `not found` on a separate line. It is standard practice to strip the `nl` (Linux) or `crnl` (Windows) from the end of any line read by either `fgets` or `getline` functions. Both read the `newline` or `crnl` and include them in `line`. You don't want strings in your code with dangling `newlines` handing off the end, so just get in the habit of removing them. I threw it in a function so it wouldn't confuse the logic of the code. What else?

Comment: If you look at `trimcrnl`, you see it gets the number of characters in `'s'` (`line` in main), then checks if the last char in `s` is a `'\n'` (newline) or `'\r'` (carriage return). If it is, then it decrements (subtracts 1 from) `len` and writes a `0` (`'\0'`) over the last character in `'s'` (removing the last `\n` or `\r`). Since `len` is now one less, when the loop executes again, it checks the last char in `s` again. If it is a `cr` or `nl` it repeats. This continues until all `crnl` have been trimmed from the end of the string (or until there are no more chars left (`len > 0`)...