# Writing a shell in C with fork() and execvp(). Why is execvp not executing anything?

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, execvp

I'm trying to implement a minimal shell using C. I will run it on a linux machine.

**Basically, execvp() does not seem to execute anything.** Why is this? I have some code that tries to see if there is an error. Any command I enter into my mini-shell returns that error statement. Also, nothing happens, a sure sign something isn't working.

The problem from the book I'm working on says to invoke `execvp()` as `execvp(args[0], args)`. I see this referenced on stackoverflow as the way to invoke it, but some also suggest `execvp(args[0],args[1])` Which one is it?

I think by now I have little to no errors in the way I'm handling user input, but if there's anything just point it out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#define MAXLINE 80

int main(void) 
{
    char *args[MAXLINE/2 + 1]; //cl w/ 40 max args
    //the above is an array of pointers-to-char
    char *s;
    int k;
    int pid;
    int lastarg;
    int status;

    int should_run = 1; //determines when to exit
    printf("CS149 Shell from MYNAME HERE\n");

    while(should_run) 
    {
        /* PROMPT */
        printf("AUTHOR-L3006323213> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        s = (char*) calloc ( 200, sizeof(char) );
        fgets(s,199,stdin);    
        /* PARSE */
        k=0;
        args[k] = strtok(s," \n\t");
        while(args[k]) 
        {
            printf("%d %s\n",k, args[k] );
            ++k;
            args[k] = strtok(NULL," \n\t");
        }

        args[k]=NULL;
        lastarg=k-1;                    

        /* HANDLE EXIT */
        if (strcmp(args[0],"exit\n") == 0)
        {
            should_run=0;
            continue;
        }    
        //fork child process using fork();
        pid = fork();    
        if(pid<0) printf("ERROR!\n");
        else if(pid==0)
        {   //child
            if(execvp(args[0], &args[1]) < 0) 
               printf("Command not found.\n");
            exit(1);
        }    
        else 
        { //parent
            //check last arg for == &
            printf("Parent is ");
            if(strcmp(args[lastarg],"&") == 0) 
               printf(" not waiting...\n");
            else 
            {
                printf("waiting...\n");
                while (wait(&status) != pid);
            }
        }    
        /* Cleanup for next prompt */
        free(s);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: So I've managed to fix somethings. I'm invoking `execvp()` using `execvp(args[0], &args[1])` now. If I give my terminal `ps &`, I see a list of processes, but another prompt *does not* show up. When I give my terminal `ps`, I do not see any list of processes at all. I think there's an issue with the parent code, and maybe with my control logic.

Comment: Using that program I don't have a problem executing anything...?

Comment: Put a `printf()` in front of your `execvp()` showing the value of the arguments you are passing to it. Check if there is any obvious solution to your problem. (Like, arguments not being what you expected.) If there isn't, reduce your example code to the two or three lines it takes to pass *exactly those parameters* to `execve()`. We don't really need your whole shell program to figure out a problem with `execve()`. Unless, of course, the problem is not `execve()` to begin with -- which should be *your* assignment to double-check, not that of every single person willing to help you.

Comment: You might like to replace `printf("Command not found.\n");` by `perror("exec failed");` to find details on the failure. Analogue for `printf("ERROR!\n");`.

Comment: Is this the same assignment : [**Writing an interpreter or more like a command prompt program**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534788/writing-an-interpreter-or-more-like-a-command-prompt-program) ?

Comment: @Mirar Really? So when you type something like `ps` it shows you the processes? I'll try running it in another VM to see if my distro was causing it...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, not quite. Same idea though.

Comment: This is nothing remotely like a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as suggested by site rules/guidelines -- a **minimal** code sample showing your problem would skip all the command line printing/parsing and go straight to the fork and the exec with hardcoded contents, including no elements not directly relevant to the specific problem at hand.

Comment: @DevSolar This helped. Since the first item in my array `arg` is just `arg[0]`, I was basically giving the program name as the first argument, like `ps ps`, which obviously doesn't make sense. I'm still trying to work out why `ps` by itself doesn't show processes, but `ps &` does

Comment: @xczv No, argv[0] is supposed to be the program name (`"ps"`).

Comment: @melpomene before I was using `execvp(args[0], args)`, but I changed it to `execvp(args[0], &args[1])`

Comment: @xczv `execvp(args[0], args)` was correct.

Comment: @melpomene I guess I'm changing it back. I tried reading the documentation on `execvp()`, but couldn't tell what it does with `args`, or that there was any guarantee of it not treating the first element of `args` (which is `args[0]`?) as an argument

Comment: @xczv It doesn't do much with `args`; it just passes them on to the program it's loading. It doesn't do anything special with the first element.

Comment: It looks like none of the changes I made in the last hour made a difference. I undid those changes, and my original code is working just fine. Weird.

Comment: You still came not up with a minimal example and / or clear description of the problem. Voting to close.