# Creating a shell in C, execv() is unable to execute most commands

Tags: c, linux, shell

So far the only commands I know to work in my shell are ls and echo. When I try something like touch or help, I either get nothing or a seg fault.

Here's my method to execute a command:

```
void mySystem(char * cmdargv[], char *searchpaths[], int numpaths, int numargs)
{
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0);
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numpaths; i++)
        {
            char * fullcmd = malloc(strlen(searchpaths[i] + strlen(cmdargv[0]) + 2));
            sprintf(fullcmd, "%s/%s", searchpaths[i], cmdargv[0]);
            //execv(fullcmd, cmdargv);
            printf("%s",fullcmd);
            free(fullcmd);

        }
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

And here's my main program:

```
int main()
{
    const char space[]="\n"; //"deliminator," specifies where to tokenize commands

int numpaths;
int numargs;
char *searchpaths[MAX_PATHS];
char *fullCMD[MAX_CMD];
InitializeArray(fullCMD, MAX_CMD);
InitializeArray(searchpaths, MAX_PATHS);

char cmd[MAX_CMD];

SaveSearchPaths(searchpaths, (int *) &numpaths); //fills the searchpaths array with
                                                 //the system PATH and returns the
                                                 //the size of the array, numpaths

while(1)
{
    printf("> ");

    fgets(cmd, MAX_CMD, stdin);

    char *token;
    token=strtok(cmd, space);

    if(strncmp(cmd,"quit",4) == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(strncmp(cmd, "path", 4)==0)
    {
        PrintAll(searchpaths, MAX_PATHS);
    }
    else
    {
        int i=0;
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            InsertStringAt(fullCMD,token,i);
            token=strtok(NULL,space);
            i++;
            numargs+=1;
        }
        mySystem(fullCMD, searchpaths, numpaths, numargs);
    }
```

The `InitializeArray()` function initializes all of the indices in the array to `NULL`. `InsertStringAt()` inserts a string into a certain index in the array, and `SaveSearchPaths()` fills the `searchpaths[]` array with the tokenized System `PATH`.

Here's what happens when I type ls into the shell:

```
./a.out
> ls
a.out arrayOfStrings.c  arrayOfStrings.h  arrayOfStrings.h.gch  arrayOfStrings.o  arrayOfStringsTester.c  arrayOfStringsTester.o  myshell.c  mySystem.c  out  SaveSearchPaths.c
```

And here's what happens when I do help:

```
$ ./a.out
> help
$
```

Nothing happens.

And here's what happens when I do touch:

```
> touch file
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006a2130 ***
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006a2130 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea why only ls seems to work?

Comment: On a side note, you could simplify your code by not bothering with all the `SearchPath` stuff and just use `execvp` which will use `PATH` in the expected way.

Comment: There is a very similar question answered here: [**Writing an interpreter or more like a command prompt program**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534788/writing-an-interpreter-or-more-like-a-command-prompt-program/32535723#32535723)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here

```
strlen(searchpaths[i] + strlen(cmdargv[0]) + 2)
/*                   ^ the ) goes here  not   ^ here
```

this is valid because you are incrementing the `searchpaths[i]` pointer and executing `strlen()` over the resulting pointer which might cause undefined behavior, but is valid code and the compiler should compile it correctly.

The correct way is

```
strlen(searchpaths[i]) + strlen(cmdargv[0]) + 2
```

Also, you should check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL` which would indicate an error.

You could prevent this, and handle more errors if you store the result of `strlen()`. It's also good IMHO to get used to it because sometimes you might need the value more than once, and since `strlen()` computes the value it's more efficient to store it in those situations, in this situations the only benefit will be clarity and improving the ability to handle errors and maintain the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, I hope this works.

```
void mySystem(char * cmdargv[], char *searchpaths[], int numpaths, int numargs)
{
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) /* remove junk semicolon */
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numpaths; i++)
        {
            char * fullcmd = malloc(strlen(searchpaths[i]) + strlen(cmdargv[0]) + 2); /* improve this expression */
            sprintf(fullcmd, "%s/%s", searchpaths[i], cmdargv[0]);
            //execv(fullcmd, cmdargv);
            printf("%s",fullcmd);
            free(fullcmd);

        }
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote, but why did you give this answer? Your answers are generally good.